# del_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username' - Django

Tags: python, django

I'am looking a solution for my problem. I have a something like a my own admin panel, and I want to create a users managment system. The first I want to create a definition to delete the registered users. But when I try to execute this def, the system responde me a error :

```
del_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

My **views.py** is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
...
def del_user(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user.delete(user)
        message.succes(request, 'Pomyślnie usunięto')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        message.error(request, 'Użytkownik nie istnieje')
    return render(request, 'konto/settings.html')
```

And I created a url to del_user.html page

```
**urls.py**

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .views import dashboard, register,settings, del_user
...
    path('del_user/', del_user, name='del_user'),
...
```

I don't understand this error why is not working. Anybody help?

Comment: What don't you understand? You've written the view to expect a `username` parameter, but haven't done anything to pass that parameter. Where are you expecting it to come from?

Comment: Daniel in your opinion what I need to add to run this def?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `username` of user to be deleted in **url**

```
 path('del-user/<slug:username>', del_user, name='del_user'),
```

Comment: `path` doesn't take regular expressions.

Comment: Ok I've change it now the url passing id user. But I have another problem with message. The system responde me : name <message> is not define. But in the top of views.py I import it.

Comment: It should be `messages.error` and not `message.error`.

Comment: Ok thank You Astik. Everythink works but the users are not deleted from database. I think I have to create a decorator :)

Comment: I did it :) :):)

Comment: Please select the answer if it helped. Thanks for cooperation